# How to play youtube video in Microsoft Media Platform Player Framework on Windows Phone/Windows

Tags: video, youtube, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

My question is very simple. Is it possible to use Microsoft Media Platform Player Framework in Windows Phone 8.1 app to play the video from youtube? I tried to provide address of the video to the source of MediaPlayer, but that does not work. Can anybody help on this one please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have made some digging in discussions on codeplex site of player framework and here is the answer: http://playerframework.codeplex.com/discussions/638055

You just need to use GetVideoUriAsync method of YouTube class, which is part of MyToolkit nuget.

```
var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync("YourYoutubeVideoID", YouTubeQuality.Quality480P);
var videoFile = url.Uri;
if (videoFile != null) videoElement.Source = videoFile;
```